# Unable to Push GitHub Package for Nuget

Tags: .net, nuget-package, github-package-registry

I followed all guidance so as to be able to push a nuget package of my class library into my private GitHub repository.

I added the following to my csproj

```
<PropertyGroup>
       <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
       <PackageId>NextWareProductPortalClientServices</PackageId>
       <Version>1.0.1</Version>
       <Authors>CodeGenerator</Authors>
       <Company>NextWare</Company>
       <PackageDescription>This package adds gRPC client library for the NextWare ProductPortal 
       </PackageDescription>
       <RepositoryUrl>https://github.com/NextWareGroup/PPD</RepositoryUrl>
 </PropertyGroup>
```

I added the following nuget.config file to the root of the project..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <packageSources>
        <clear />
        <add key="github" value="https://nuget.pkg.github.com/jkears/index.json" />
    </packageSources>
    <packageSourceCredentials>
        <github>
            <add key="Username" value="jkears" />
            <add key="ClearTextPassword" value="******6d5a57b7527dfcc646b62ca7d1*****" />
        </github>
    </packageSourceCredentials>
</configuration>
```

The Personal Token has all permissions applied.

After running the dotnet cli to create the package I see the package in the bin\release folder.
Then I attempt to run the following command...

```
dotnet nuget push "bin/Release/NextWareProductPortalClientServices.1.0.1.nupkg" --source "github"
```

The output is as follows;

```
warn : No API Key was provided and no API Key could be found for 'https://nuget.pkg.github.com/jkears'. To save an API Key for a source use the 'setApiKey' command.
Pushing NextWareProductPortalClientServices.1.0.1.nupkg to 'https://nuget.pkg.github.com/jkears'...
  PUT https://nuget.pkg.github.com/jkears/
An error was encountered when fetching 'PUT https://nuget.pkg.github.com/jkears/'. The request will now be retried.
An error occurred while sending the request.
  The response ended prematurely.
  PUT https://nuget.pkg.github.com/jkears/
An error was encountered when fetching 'PUT https://nuget.pkg.github.com/jkears/'. The request will now be retried.
An error occurred while sending the request.
  The response ended prematurely.
  PUT https://nuget.pkg.github.com/jkears/
error: An error occurred while sending the request.
error:   The response ended prematurely.
```

I have researched this issue but none of the reported fixes work for me, including running directly from Nuget CLI.

Comment: I've the same problem. Can you try this `dotnet nuget push "bin/Release/NextWareProductPortalClientServices.1.0.1.nupkg" --source "github" --api-key YOUR_API_KEY`. This solves my API_KEY problem but now I'm getting No destination repository detected error.

Comment: I think above command solves your problem but after that you can get the same error as me.

Comment: Thanks @KenanNur.   Later today I will try youe solution, perhaps collectively we will get this to work.  In my case the curl based solution will work for my needs.  I code generate microservices following DDD principals and my need to push as nuget packages it to support integration with previously generated class libraries from other domain models.  I just need a CLI type approach that I can run in the GitHub Action flows, and the curl solution should be enough to support that need.

Answer (score 2):

While not the answer I was able to push the nuget package using the following curl command..

curl -vX PUT -u "[OwnerName]:[PersonalToken]" -F package=@NextWareProductPortalClientServices.1.0.1.nupkg  https://nuget.pkg.github.com/jkears/

I am not sure why the DotNet CLI does not work, but the above does which is all I need.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this issue as well and it happens consistently with *relatively large* packages (in my case about 3.4MB). I conclude it's an issue with **dotnet nuget**. Strangely the problem does **NOT** happen to the standalone Nuget client (downloaded at https://www.nuget.org/downloads), or as you already knew, crafting a PUT request using `curl` or a HTTP client.

This is the `nuget` command that successfully upload the package:

```
nuget push -Source "github" -SkipDuplicate $file.FullName
```

I reported [the issue here](https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/35888).